# Angular2 watch for 302 redirect when fetching resource

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I have a requirement to pull a few resources from another domain held by my company. I want to pull secured HTML content with GET requests.

When a user is signed out of the application the requested content will return a 302 to the login page.

My attempts to sniff the headers for a 302 haven't returned what I'd hoped for so far. The response returned by my Observable is a 200 (login page).

Here is my sample app.

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

    private _resourceUrl = "http://localhost:3001/resources/menu";

    constructor(private _http: Http){
    }

    menu: string;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getMenu()
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    console.log(`Response status: ${response.status}`);

                    this.menu = response.text();
                },
                error => console.log(<any>error));
    }

    getMenu(): Observable<Response>{        
        return this._http.get(this._resourceUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => response)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response){
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
    }
}
```

Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the server sends a redirect with a 302 status code with the URL to redirect within a `Location` header, the redirect is automatically handled by the browser, i.e. a request to this URL is executed.

That's why XHR (and the Angular2 wrapper around it, i.e. the `Http` class) won't see the result of the first request but only the response of the second one.

Comment: can you explain a bit more...(beginner here)

Comment: So, I cannot control my application flow with a 302 redirect?

Comment: IE11 is interpreting 302 response with empty string as error. Any suggestions on getting HttpService to handle redirects inside IE11 properly?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The OP was asking how to detect it.

Comment: @speciesUnknown It does answer the question because there is no way of detecting the 302 redirect because the browser takes control of the request before our Angular code has a chance to check the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code for redirecting to ServiceData. Angular2(4) and ASP net Core.

```
private post(url: string, data?: any) {
    return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.headers })
      .map(response => this.extractData(response, true));
}

private extractData(res: Response, mapJson = true) {
    let body: any = res;
    // redirect
    if (body.url.search('ReturnUrl') != -1) {
        let url = new URL(body.url);

        // get patch redirect simple /account/login
        let pathname = url.pathname;

        // get params redirect simple ?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fitems%2FGetitems
        let search = url.search;

        // 1 navigate with params
        this.router.navigate.navigate([pathname], { queryParams: { returnUrl: search } });

        // OR ...

        // 2 navigate only pathname
        this.router.navigate.navigate([pathname]);
        return {};
    }            

    if (mapJson) {
        body = body.json();
    }
    return body || {};
}
```